# How to find all ocurrences of an element in all columns of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find all ocurrences of an element in a DataFrame. I'm using `str.count` and `str.contains` but I can't get a function to get the sum of all the elements.

```py
df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.count('word'), axis=1)
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

# Something like this
df.apply(lambda row: sum(row.astype(str).str.count('word')), axis=1)
0    4
1    0
2    0

# Expected output:
4
```

Comment: You want sum of each row?

Comment: @JoeFerndz the sum of the element in all the DataFrame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do `stack` , then do not need `apply`

```
df.stack().astype(str).str.count('word').sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Python comprehension

This may look ugly but is fairly quick.

```
sum([x.count('word') for row in zip(*map(df.astype(str).get, df)) for x in row])

4
```

---

#### Numpy

You'd think this is quick but it isn't

```
np.char.count(df.to_numpy().astype(str), 'word').sum()

4
```

---

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[*'abababbbab'], [*'c'*10], [*'d'*10]],
    columns=[*'ABCDEFGHIJ']
).replace({'a': 'word', 'b': 'other', 'c': 'not', 'd': 'it'})

df

      A      B     C      D     E      F      G      H     I      J
0  word  other  word  other  word  other  other  other  word  other
1   not    not   not    not   not    not    not    not   not    not
2    it     it    it     it    it     it     it     it    it     it
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I got an answer, but I don't know if the most efficient way to do it

```py
df.apply(lambda row: sum(row.astype(str).str.count('word')), axis=1).to_numpy().sum()

4
```